# How to create element ID based from class name

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an element with ID of the element class name...

my codes

```
//$elementClass has no id attrbute

          elementID=$elementClass.attr('class');

               $elementClass.first().attr('id',elementID);
               $element=$(elementID);               
               console.log($element);   

//the console.log doesn't output anything....
```

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try first `console.log(elementID)` and see what you get... maybe you can figure it out yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your class has the `#` character in it, all you get is the class name value. You need to add the `#` character to your selector if you want to select the element with that id.

```
$element=$('#' + elementID);
```

However, seeing you are executing `first()` already to get the element of interest you might as well cache that object at that point and use it from there on.

```
// Get the id value from the class name
elementID = $elementClass.attr('class');

// Create a jQuery object of the element I want to update
var $element = $elementClass.first();

// Update the element
$element.attr('id',elementID);

// Show the results in the console
console.log($element);
```

That should work too and it saves you having to concatenate selector values.